# How to call SSIS package

Tags: ssis, etl

The requirement is to execute SSIS package , when a mail is arrived in outlook,and the package has to start executing.

We are not sure about the mail arrival timing ,but will be fro sure in between 2:00 am to 5:30 am.Also the mail will arrive only one time with a same subject line every day.Also the mail backup has to be stored in local folder.

Please help me.

Comment: More of an Outlook/Exchange question than an SSIS one.  If you can get the mail client or server to run an .EXE when a certain mail arrives, the rest is easy: just look up the command-line switches for DTEXEC https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just schedule the package at 5:30; that way you know it has arrived.